# Xpath gives different result on browser and in scrapy

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I was trying to scrape the python course information from this site: 
https://www.udemy.com/topic/python/.

I wrote an xpath to select the title text:

> //div[@data-purpose='course-card-title']/text()

This works when I test it on chrome and it gives 39 matches, but I get an empty list on scrapy.

Comment: Scrapy is not executing the javascript, which your normal chrome browser does, that is why you don't see the data. The site you are using needs javascript. So either use selenium or use Scrapy with splash

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment by [Tarun Lalwani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056400/xpath-gives-different-result-on-browser-and-in-scrapy#comment109756141_62056400) the data you see in your browser is created using Javascript. One way could be to use Selenium or Scrapy with splash, another is to find the API-calls that were made and use them directly.

Make use of the DevTools of your browser (ctrl + shift + c) and check the Network-tab. See what happens once you reload the page. You should notice that there are requests made to their API, which you can use and manipulate to get the data you are looking for. From the response in json-format you can extract the data you are looking for.

The following is a minimal working example that prints the titles of the courses you see on the top part of https://www.udemy.com/topic/python/:

```py
import scrapy
import json


class UdemySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "udemy"
    start_urls = ['https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/discovery-units/?context=topic&from=0&page_size=10&item_count=12&excluded_course_ids=&label_id=7380&source_page=topic_page&locale=de_DE&currency=eur&navigation_locale=en_US&skip_price=true']

    def parse(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())

        for item in jsonresponse['units'][0]['items']:
            print(item['title'])
```

The printed result (at least for users from Germany) will look like this:

```
Python Bootcamp: Vom Anfänger zum Profi, inkl. Data Science
Python für Data Science, Machine Learning & Visualization
Data Science & Maschinelles Lernen in Python - am Beispiel
Machine Learning Komplettkurs mit Python inkl. AI Einführung
Python Bootcamp: Der Einstiegskurs
Python - Das Python Grundlagen Bootcamp - Von 0 auf 100!
Visualisiere Daten mit Python - auch für Anfänger!
Data Science, Apache Spark & Python: Analysiere echte Daten!
Fortgeschrittene Python Programmierung
Complete Python Bootcamp: Go from zero to hero in Python 3
Machine Learning A-Z™: Hands-On Python & R In Data Science
Python for Data Science and Machine Learning Bootcamp
```